# Postgres: update a JSON array inside a nested JSON object if array exists otherwise create it

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I'm trying to perform an update on a Postgres column that contains a JSON object.

This is how the object that I want to update is structured:

```
{
    steps: {
        step1: [{ a: 1, b: 2 }],
        step2: [{ c: 3, d: 4 }]
        ... // N steps can be dynamically inserted, I do not know them at object insertion
    }
}
```

Inside the property *steps* I can have step1, step2, step3, etc.. in a dynamic way; so, for example, I might skip step3 but have step4.

So I cannot create them before hand but I need to add them dynamically.


Every stepX contains an array.

I'm trying to add a value in the array of a stepX if the step already exists, otherwise I want to create the new step and initialize the array with a value.
I want to do this with **ONLY one** instruction, is it possible?

So far I managed to insert an element in the array if the stepX already exists using this instruction:

```
jsonb_insert(outputs, '{ steps, step1, 1}','{"l":10}') // adding element in step1 array
```

This code works only if step1 already exists. If I run the same command with a step that does not exist, for example step100, the property in the object is not gonna be created

```
jsonb_insert(outputs, '{ steps, step100, 1}','{"b":2}')
```

Any idea on how I can solve this?

Comment: Try:  `select jsonb_set(outputs, '{steps,step2}', coalesce(outputs->'steps'->'step2', '[]')||'{"l": 10}')`

Comment: @MikeOrganek thanks for answering! I tried the snippet you shared and there was a small error but it helped me to get to the final solution which is:

`jsonb_set(outputs, '{steps,step5}', coalesce(outputs -> 'steps' -> 'step5', '[]') || '[{"l":10}]':: jsonb)`

wrapping the obj { l: 10 } inside an array did the trick :)

Comment: That's odd because it works for me here:  https://dbfiddle.uk/_6Y6JBKa